# How can I pad lots of file names with zeros in a directory?

Tags: files, rename

I just wrote a script that generated hundreds of files and stored them in a directory `~/foo`. These files are `~/foo/X-file` where `X` ranges from `X=1` to `X=900`. My problem is that I would like to view these files in numerical order, but the files are not padded with zeros. Thus the directory contains `17-file` and `544-file` for example. Is there a way to pad these files with leading zeros?

Answer (score 5):

```
cd ~/foo
for i in *-file; do
    num=${i%-file}
    padnum=$(printf '%03d' $num)
    mv -v "$i" "${padnum}-file"
done
```

Something along these lines should do it. Modify as necessary for precise patterns and directories.

Answer (score 4):

If you have the Perl `rename` utility (often called `prename`, not the more primitive Linux one):

```
rename -v 's/^([0-9]-)/00$1/; s/^([0-9]{2}-)/0$1/' *-file
```

- The first regular expression replaces single digits with two zeros (2->002)
- The second one replaces two digits with with one zero (33->033)

Answer (score -1):

The following should work in bash if run in the directory you care about.

```
for x in [0-9]*-file ; do mv $x `printf %03d-%s ${x%-*} ${x##*-}` ; done
```